# How to combine `annularWedge` and `wedge` from Haskell's diagrams package?

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

It turns out that the [`annularWedge`](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-TwoD-Arc.html) function of the diagrams package cannot take a radius of 0 for the inner radius. You must use `wedge` instead.

To me, an inner radius of 0 is just the degenerate case of `annularWedge` and should behave like `wedge`, so I tried to combine them:

```
mywedge r2 r1 d a
  | r1 == 0   = wedge r2 d a
  | otherwise = annularWedge r2 r1 d a
```

Of course, it doesn't work, and I cannot figure out what the error means:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: RealFloat (N t)
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
When checking that ‘mywedge’ has the inferred type
  mywedge :: forall t.
             (RealFloat (N t), TrailLike t, V t ~ V2) =>
             N t -> N t -> Direction V2 (N t) -> Angle (N t) -> t
```

In fact, it turns out that `annularWedge` and `wedge` have different constraints, which surprised me:

```
annularWedge :: (TrailLike t, V t ~ V2, N t ~ n, RealFloat n) => n -> n -> Direction V2 n -> Angle n -> t

wedge :: (InSpace V2 n t, OrderedField n, TrailLike t) => n -> Direction V2 n -> Angle n -> t
```

So how do I combine these two functions into a sane one that accepts an inner radius of 0 and does the right thing?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly give `mywedge` the same type as `annularWedge`?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple. As ErikR said, add `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}` to the top of your file. To be clear, these are both safe extensions to add (some extensions, like overlapping instances or undecidable instances should make you pause before you enable them, but these extensions are [mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229572/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-using-flexiblecontexts-and-flexibleinstances) safe)

Although it isn't obvious, the `wedge` signature's constraints are strictly weaker than the `annularWedge`s ones.

#### If you are curious as to why the signatures look so different, read on...

For starters, the constraints, once you track them down, aren't all that different. Let's start with `wedge`.

```
(InSpace V2 n t, OrderedField n, TrailLike t)
```

Looking at the definition of [`InSpace`](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-Core-V.html#t:InSpace), you see that it has no functions, it's essentially like a synonym: `(V a ~ v, N a ~ n, Additive v, Num n) => InSpace v n a`. Then, we can expand `InSpace V2 n t` to `(V t ~ V2, N t ~ n, Additive V2, Num n)`. Similarly, [`OrderedField`](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-Core-Envelope.html#t:OrderedField) turns out to just be shorthand for `(Floating n, Ord n)`. Now, the constraint for `wedge` looks like

```
(TrailLike t, V t ~ V2, N t ~ n, Additive V2, Num n, Floating n, Ord n)
```

However, it turns out that we can even drop the `Additive V2` constraint, since that instance is defined [where `Additive` is defined in `Linear.Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/Linear-Vector.html#t:Additive) and `Num n` is redundant, given that `Num n => Fractional n => Floating n`. That leaves us with the much simpler constraint for `wedge`

```
(TrailLike t, V t ~ V2, N t ~ n, Floating n, Ord n)
```

Which looks a whole lot like the constraint for `annularWedge`. In fact, the only difference is that `wedge` constrains `(Floating n, Ord n)` compared to `annularWedge` constraining `RealFloat n`. At this point, the constraints are similar enough to make it worth looking at the code for `wedge`. It turns out that `wedge` makes use of `_theta`, defined in [`HasTheta`](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-Angle.html#t:HasTheta) and the [corresponding `V2` instance](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/src/Diagrams-TwoD-Types.html#line-50) uses an arctangent function (which, you get after chasing through a couple more dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the suggestions that GHC gives you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Diagrams
import Diagrams.TwoD.Arc

mywedge r2 r1 d a
  | r1 == 0   = wedge r2 d a
  | otherwise = annularWedge r2 r1 d a
```

In general, though, I prefer to use a `<=` comparison when dealing
with floating point numbers, i.e. something like:

```
  | r1 <= 1e-10 = wedge r2 d 1
```